# Filtering Columns in PLSQL

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-apex

I have a table with tons and tons of columns and I'm trying to select only certain columns based on the data the columns contain.  The table is part of an application I'm building in Oracle APEX and looks something like this:

```
|Row Header|Criteria 1|Criteria 2| Criteria 3 | Criteria 4 |Criteria 5 |
|Category  | Type A   | Type B   | Type B     | Type A     | Type A    |
| ID       | 2.3      | 2.4      | 2.5        | 3.1        | 3.2       |
| Part A   | Yes      | Yes      | Yes        | No         | Yes       |
| Part B   | Yes      | No       | Yes        | Yes        | Yes       |
| Part C   | No       | Yes      | Yes        | Yes        | No        |
```

It goes on like this for around 1000ish criteria and 100ish parts I need to find a way to select all the columns that are of a specific type to its own table using SQL.

Id Like the return to look like this:

```
|Row Header|Criteria 1|Criteria 5 |
|Category  | Type A   | Type A    |
| ID       | 3.1      | 3.2       |
| Part A   | No       | Yes       |
| Part B   | Yes      | Yes       |
| Part C   | Yes      | No        |
```

This way I only have the columns showing that are part of the "Type A" Category and have an ID greater than 3.

I've looked into GROUP BY and FILTER functions that SQL has to offer as well as PIVOT and I don't believe these will help me, but I'd be happy to be proven wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In a relational database, columns are meant to be discrete, non-repeating attributes of a thing. Rows are meant to be multiple instances of that thing. Your table is reversed, using columns for what should be rows, and rows for what should be columns. Another factor is that Oracle limits you to 1000 columns, and you start undergoing severe performance degradation when you exceed 254 columns. Tables simply weren't meant to have hundreds, let alone thousands, of columns. So first step is to pivot your table like this:

```
       Criteria_No, Cat,   ID,  PtA, PtB, PtC
---------------------------------------------
Row 1: Criteria 1, Type A, 2.3, Yes, Yes, No
Row 2: Criteria 2, Type B, 2.4, Yes, No, Yes
Row 3: Criteria 3, Type B, 2.5, Yes, Yes, Yes
. . . thousands more
```

But even then, you mentioned that you have 100s of "parts", so Parts A, B, C aren't the only three - the series continues. If so, it would be a violation of normal form to have such a repeating list in a single row. So you have one more step to fix your design: Break this into three tables.

```
CRITERIA
       Criteria_No, Cat,   ID
---------------------------------------------
Row 1: Criteria 1, Type A, 2.3
Row 2: Criteria 2, Type B, 2.4
Row 3: Criteria 3, Type B, 2.5

PARTS
Part, anything-else-about-part
-----------------
Part A, blah
Part B, blah,
Part C, blah
. . .
```

And now the bridge table between them:

```
CRITERIA_PARTS
Criteria_No, Part
-----------------
1, Part A
1, Part B
1, Part C
2, Part A,
2, Part B,
. . . and so on
```

You should also place a foreign key on each of the bridge table columns to point to their respective parent tables to ensure data integrity.

Now you query by joining the tables together in your SQL.

Updated: you asked how to move data into this new criteria table from your existing one. Use dynamic SQL like this:

```
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..1000
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO criteria (criteria_no,cat,id) SELECT criteria_'||i||',category,id FROM oldtable';
  END LOOP;

  COMMIT;
END;
```

But of course set the 1000 to the real # of category_n columns.

Comment: I believe this would bring up another problem for me.  I don't know where we would store the the yes' and no's that are the entire point of the database in your example.  Each part needs to meet the 1000 criteria and its progress towards meeting it is tracked in the table I provided.

Comment: The very presence of a Part B for criteria 1 means Yes for that criteria. The lack of any such row means No. That would be appropriate in most situations. If however your data is highly volatile and you will be constantly flipping Yes to No and No to Yes, then you can model every possible combination of criteria_no and part using the CRITERIA_PARTS table I illustrated, but add a third column Y/N. But if your data is relatively static, it's better to just let the presence of a row indicate a relationship and the lack of a row to indicate the absence of a relationship. That's normal for DBs.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help, is there any easy way to get all of the criteria from the table in my current format to the format you titled the criteria table?

Comment: With a few columns you can use a series of MAX(DECODE()) to pick the correct column for a given pseudo row number, having generated a set of dummy rows for this purpose.  But you said you had a 1000 criteria? That would be an excessively large SQL statement. You can't have more than 1000 columns, so assuming you are right at 1000, I would suggest perhaps writing a PL/SQL loop that uses dynamic SQL (execute immediate) to pull out column by column and insert them as rows.

Comment: Edited my answer with a simple PL/SQL script